# crear una vista en mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Hola como puedo crear una vista en el cual me muestre un resumen de las solicitudes por convocatoria, en caso de no contar alguna solicitud deberá mostrar un 0, solo que estoy confundida en la parte de que muestre un 0

esta es mi tabla

```
CREATE TABLE ProgramaCategoria(
    Id          INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    Nombre      VARCHAR(100),
    IdPrograma  INT,
    
    CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (IdPrograma) REFERENCES Programa(Id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

y esto es lo que llevo de mi vista

```
create view vista_apoyo as 
select distinct * from programacategoria
;
```

Comment: ¿esa vista da algún error?

Comment: no, si me da la vista pero lo unico que me falta es cuando no cuenta con alguna debe mostrar 0 pero ando confundida en esa parte

Comment: una vista no es lo mejor para hacerlo, necesitas un procedure

Comment: Aquí hay un ejemplo perfecto a tu solución https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9487963/mysql-query-to-return-number-zero-if-no-results